# Application Icon Is not Appearing On System Tray

Tags: java, system-tray

I used system tray class to place my application on that but instead my application icon appear there appear's an empty space and it worked perfectly but my app icon is not visible there.
Please give me solution to it :)

Comment: it is not possible to use ue win system icons, use external icons

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  without it we can't help you.